# Is there any Android browser reference/documentation?

Tags: android, web-applications, browser, mobile, webkit

Is there any Android browser reference/documentation for Web app developers? Something like Apple's [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Introduction/Introduction.html) would be fantastic.

I am exploring options to make Android Web app more native-like, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike iOS Safari, there is no documentation on the Android browser that provides mobile-specific features.

Answer (score 2):

Funny you ask, I just stumbled across this [article](http://designbycode.tumblr.com/post/1127120282/pixel-perfect-android-web-ui) today, not a full guide but helpful info I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

I also found a nice [blog post](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/using-mobile-specific-html-css-javascript) on mobile-specific HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The other articles of his mobile web series can be found towards the end of the article.